# Ruby on Rails: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason I am getting an error on this method when I am trying to add a record.
The specific error is 
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

```
    def addrecord
        res=MultiGeocoder.geocode(params[:street], params[:city], params[:state])
        lat, lng = res.ll.split(",") 
        Bathroom.create(:name =>params[:name],
                        :bathroomtype =>params[:bathroomtype],
                        :street =>params[:street],
                        :city =>params[:city],
                        :state =>params[:state],
                        :country =>params[:country],
                        :postal =>params[:postal],
                        :lat => lat,
                        :lon => lng,
                        :access =>params[:access], 
                        :directions =>params[:directions],
                        :comment =>params[:comment],
                        :created => Time.now,
                        :source => 'Squat',
                        :avail =>params[:avail] )
                        respond_to do |format|
                          format.json   { render :nothing => true }                  

                        end

      end

    This is an example call...

> http:..../bathrooms/addrecord?name=Apple%20Store&bathroomtype=1&street=One%20Stockton%20St.&city=San%20Francisco&state=CA&country=United%20States&postal=94108&access=0&directions=&comment=&avail=0
```

This is the request parms:

Request

Parameters:

```
{"city"=>"San Francisco",
 "avail"=>"0",
 "access"=>"0",
 "bathroomtype"=>"1",
 "comment"=>"",
 "country"=>"United States",
 "directions"=>"",
 "name"=>"Apple Store",
 "street"=>"One Stockton St.",
 "postal"=>"94108",
 "state"=>"CA"}
```

What am I missing?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a location as the first parameter here, and options as the rest:

```
MultiGeocoder.geocode(params[:street], params[:city], params[:state])
```

Try to send it as a string, like this:

```
MultiGeocoder.geocode("#{params[:street]}, #{params[:city]}, #{params[:state]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in `master` for **[Geokit](https://github.com/imajes/geokit)**, *(the gem I'm assuming you're using)*, `MultiGeocoder` extends `Geocoder`, who's method signature for `geocode` **[only expects 2 arguments](https://github.com/imajes/geokit/blob/master/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb#L96)**, an `address` and optional `options` hash.

Comment: how would i specify the city and state as an options hash?

Comment: You wouldn't. Read the docs in the link I provided; that's not what `options` is for. You would do something like @MauricioPasquierJuan suggested in his answer. My answer nudges you in the right direction and explains what you're missing (a clear understanding of the API) as you requested :)